# Prestashop - default category image

Tags: prestashop, categories, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop version 1.6.9

Unfortunately I have lots of categories that don't have pictures so the page looks when browsing category like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWOG3.jpg .
Another weird thing is that the picture is returned with 404 status code.

Now, I want to use some default image when there is no special image for category.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's kind of strange, because that image is used everywhere, where the image is set, but doest exist in file.

The image used here is `img/404.gif`, but if you change it, it will be used in other places too.

If you want to change category images (sub-category images I assume?) then you should modify the template files of your theme and add a link to your custom image. For example,

themes/default-bootstrap/category.tpl @ Line: 80

```
{if $subcategory.id_image}
    <img class="replace-2x" src="{$link->getCatImageLink($subcategory.link_rewrite, $subcategory.id_image, 'medium_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="" width="{$mediumSize.width}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" />
{else}
    <img class="replace-2x" src="{$img_cat_dir}default-medium_default.jpg" alt="" width="{$mediumSize.width}" height="{$mediumSize.height}" />
{/if}
```

Comment: Hi gskema, 

thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. I've changed the code you point me on, so it works now in way I want.

For some reason, the if condition {if $subcategory.id_image} is interpreted as true in my case, so prestashop tries to load not existing image and returns 404.gif.

Thanks again!